# Push notification on click event does not work when app is in background Ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3, phonegap-pushplugin

1. I am using **phonegap-plugin-push** for push notification in Ionic 3
2. I received notification, but while clicking on notification I didn't get any response.
3. I want to redirect to a selected page while clicking on notification. Below is my code.

   ```
   public pushNotification(){
     const options: PushOptions = {
       android: {
         senderID: 'xxxxxxxx',
         icon: 'icon',
         sound: true,
         vibrate: true
       },
       ios: {
         alert: true,
         badge: true,
         sound: true,
       }
     };

     let isNotifyAvailable: boolean = false;
     const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);
     let me = this;
     pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
       console.log('Received a notification', notification);
       if (notification.additionalData.foreground) {
         me.utilService.showToastMsg("success", notification.message);
       } else {
             this.navCtrl.setRoot(NotificationList);
       }
     });
   }
   ```
4. In the backend I am using **FCM** notification in Python.

How can I redirect in selected page when click on Notification?

Comment: Where you able to trigger the event handler on background?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (notification.additionalData.foreground) {
            // code as your functionality
} else {
        console.log("else", notification);
        this.handleNofication(notification.additionalData);
}

handleNofication(data) {
// here you can also pass data
    this.app.getRootNav().setRoot("RosterPage", { direction: "forward" });
  }
```

Comment: i didn't get notification.additionalData.foreground === false, so the **ELSE** condition was not execute.

Comment: Then you can follow this code by putting log of notification